# total number of games reviewed by 100 reviewers with average points

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table called wrestling that looks like:

name is the reviewer of the game, id is the game, and points are the points that the reviewer gave to the wrestler.

name, id, points

bob, 1, 4.0

tom, 1, 3.5

phil, 1, 2.0

bob, 2, 1.5

bob, 3, 2.5

.

.

.

I want to find the total number of games that are reviewed by at least 100 reviewers and with
average points >= 2.

I am trying to execute mysqlite commands to get this total number. I know I need to use count(*) and maybe GROUP BY name, id and then sum the points and divide by how many there are but this is not working out for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group only by id and use the having condition

```
 select count(*) from ( select id, count(*) as reviewers, sum(points)/count(*) as avg from wrestling group by id having count(*) > 100 and sum(points)/count(*)>2 )
```

Comment: Great thanks, this gives me a list of all of the movies but I just needed a number at the end like there were 325 games with these conditions

Comment: How would I add a count condition so only like 325 is printed out

Comment: Worked great! What does count(*) as reviewers do?

Comment: It counts the number of duplicated rows with the same id. They are the number of reviewers of that id